# How is my object method being hacked in this example?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Hi all I have been learning coffeescript from the book **Mark Bates programming in coffeescript pdf** I have been banging my head off at the behavior of javascript even though both seems to have same implementation

**Example-1**

```
class Employee
  constructor: (@attributes)->
    for key, value of @attributes
      @[key] = value
  printInfo: ->
    alert "Name: #{@name}"
emp1 = new Employee
  name: "Mark"
  printInfo: ->
    alert "Hacked ur code !"

emp1.printInfo()
```

**Corresponding javascript**

```
var Emp, Employee, emp1, emp2;

Employee = (function() {

  function Employee(attributes) {
    var key, value, _ref;
    this.attributes = attributes;
    _ref = this.attributes;
    for (key in _ref) {
      value = _ref[key];
      this[key] = value;
    }
  }

  Employee.prototype.printInfo = function() {
    return alert("Name: " + this.name);
  };

  return Employee;

})();

emp1 = new Employee({
  name: "Mark",
  printInfo: function() {
    return alert("Hacked ur code !");
  }
});

emp1.printInfo();
```

```
 This alerts "Hacked ur code !"
```

**Example-2**

```
class Emp
  constructor: (@attributes)->
  printInfo: ->
    alert "Name: #{@attributes.name}"
emp2 = new Emp
  name: "Mark"
  printInfo: ->
    alert "Hacked ur code"
emp2.printInfo()
```

**Corresponding javascript**

```
Emp = (function() {

  function Emp(attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }

  Emp.prototype.printInfo = function() {
    return alert("Name: " + this.attributes.name);
  };

  return Emp;

})();

emp2 = new Emp({
  name: "Mark",
  printInfo: function() {
    return alert("Hacked ur code");
  }
});

emp2.printInfo();
```

```
 This alerts "Name: Mark"
```

Where is the difference ?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/yAHDZ/ but this alerts "Name: Mark", are you sure that it alerts "Hacked ur code"? In fact the first example should alert "Hacked your code"

Comment: oops, edited the question now...but my doubt is why is the difference ? why doesn't the second one alert "Hacked ur code !" ?

Comment: "Hacked" as in "dirty-evil-hacker" is a bit over the top here - the first implementation just allows to overwrite the method when you're not careful enough with the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, all properties of the object you pass to the constructor (`attributes`) are added to the current instance (that's what the loop does). Instance properties hide prototype properties, that's why the `printInfo` function you passed to the constructor is executed. You can access the original method by using `Employee.prototype.printInfo.call(emp1);`

In the second example, nothing like this happens. The `attributes` object just lives inside the `attributes` property of the instance. To get a different alert, you need to write `emp2.attributes.printInfo();`

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the following code is adding a `printInfo` property to the object:

```
_ref = this.attributes;
for (key in _ref) {
  value = _ref[key];
  this[key] = value;
}
```

Pay close attention to `this[key] = value;` where it is adding a "direct property" to the object, so when a property look up is performed by the JS engine, it finds your "printInfo" method right there in the object itself, so it does not go down to the Prototype chain and invoke the method that you have defined out there. Now if you use `Object.hasOwnProperty` to test the `printInfo` property of the `emp1` object you'll see that it returns true (which means that it is a direct property object and not a inherited one from the prototype chain).

The `Object.hasOwnProperty()` reference:
[hasOwnProperty method reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)